# Different bases question

Tags: number-theory

What is the greatest 3-digit number in base 11?

I thought it was 11^3-1=1330 which is apparently wrong.

How many symbols are needed in each base system?

Base 7 and Base 4

I have no idea

Comment: 999 is the greatest 3 digit number

Comment: I get $1330_{10}$ as well.  What makes you think that is wrong?

Comment: The largest $3$-digit number in base eleven is indeed $11^3-1$, which in base ten is $1330$. Perhaps the answer was supposed to be in base eleven, in which case it would be $TTT$ if $T$ is the symbol used for the largest digit. For the rest, in base ten we need ten symbols, $0,1,\ldots,9$. Essentially the same thing happens in any integer base $b$: we need symbols for $0,1,\ldots,b-1$, so we need $b$ symbols.

Comment: In base $b$ you have digits $0,1,2,3,\dots,(b-1)$ (*using a total of $b$ symbols*).  The largest three digit number in base $b$ is expressed in base $b$ as the number $(b-1)(b-1)(b-1)$ where these are each digits, not multiplication.  Using the symbol $a$ to denote ten, we have in base eleven, the largest three digit number is expressed as $aaa$.

Comment: If we assume $9_{11} = 10_{11}-1$ or $9_{11} = 10_{10} $.  The answer would be $999_{11}=10*11^2 +10*11+10=1330_{11} $.  But I think must people use $9_{11}=9_{10} $ and that the digit for base 11 is one that doesn't exist in base 10.  We have to make one up.  So $A_{11}=10_{10} $ and the largest is $AAA_{11}=1330_{10} $.

Comment: The number of symbols in base N (anything) is N.  That's why it is called "base N".  So for base 11 you need 11 symbols so you have to make one up to represent $10_{10} $.  We can use any symbol we want.  Say...A.  then the largest number is $AAA $ which represents $10*11^2+10*11+10=11^3-1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The largest $3$-digit number in base ten is $999$: we used the largest digit three times.

The same thing applies in other bases. Since in base $b$ we have that
$$\underbrace{abcd\ldots z}_{\text{$n$ digits}} = a \times b^{n - 1} + b \times b^{n - 2} + \cdots + z$$
the largest value is obtained when all the coefficients are the maximum possible. It happens when we select the largest digit.

In base eleven, let's call the largest digit $t = 11 - 1 = 10$. Then the largest $3$-digit value is
$$ttt_{11} = t \times 11^2 + t \times 11 + t = 1330.$$